# Windows update searches(error) with service disabled(win7)

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

I'm trying to run windows update on a machine with an image, a colleague made some time back. But every time I search for updates it gives me the 8007000E error.
I have tried turning the service off, but it still tries to search for updates and gives me the same error.

It's a 32-bit Win7 SP1 with latest updates being from January 2016.

I've tried a bunch of stuff from [this MS article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2509997) and so far nothing works.

Error message is:

> An error occured while checking for new updates for your computer.

***Edit***: I ran sfc /scannow and it told me I had corrupt windows files that it could not fix. Same goes for the MS Fixit I ran.

***Update***: I tried to install the newest version of the Windows Update agent, it didn't work.

***Update 2***: I tried repairing with the windows disc, did not work either.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the error was caused by a bad update in the image.

Using WSUS Offline Updater, I forced newer updates on the machine, and it solved my issue.